# How to Plot line chart using R for time-series analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, linechart

I am trying to plot a line chart using Date-time and no of tweets at that period of date and time in R.

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2020-03-12", 
            "2020-03-13"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
            3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("00:00:00Z", "00:00:01Z", "00:10:04Z", 
            "00:25:12Z", "01:00:02Z"), class = "factor"), Text = structure(c(5L, 
            3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("The images of demonstrations and gathering", "Premium policy get activate by company abc", 
            "Launches of rocket", "Premium policy get activate by company abc", 
            "Technology makes trend", "The images of demonstrations and gatherings", 
            "Weather forecasting by xyz"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            -6L))
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Date, y = text(count)) + geom_line(aes(color = variable), size = 1)
```

I tried the above code to plot desired result but got an error. Dataset given like that in csv format.

```
Date         Time                     Text
2020-03-12   00:00:00Z                The images of demonstrations and gatherings
2020-03-12   00:00:00Z                Premium policy get activate by company abc
2020-03-12   00:00:01Z                Weather forecasting by xyz 
2020-03-12   00:10:04Z                Technology makes trend
2020-03-12   00:25:12Z                Launches of rocket 
2020-03-12   01:00:02Z                Government launch new policy to different sector improvement
```

I have a dataset of nearly 15 days and want to plot the line chart to visualize the number of tweets (given in text column) to see the trend of tweets on different time and date.

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your data `df1` as a data frame object in your question to make your question reproducible? ideally `df1 <-  data.frame(...)` where ... comprises the variables and values of a sample of your data. Or use `dput(head(df1, 20))` see [reprex]

Comment: yes @Peter number of tweets per hour

Comment: with regard to frequency is that per hour of the day i.e. from 0 - 24 hours or per day hour i.e.  day 1 hours 0-24 followed by day 2 hours 0-24

Comment: @Peter I think you should able to access df1 now. Yes on given dataset plot shows number of tweets i.e. given text column in data frame df1. Visualize the count on line plot

Comment: My own data @VaibhavSingh

Comment: When you read your csv file do you use the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. This would make data wrangling easier as your dates and times have become factors which might not  be the most efficient way to achieve what you want.

Comment: You may be better off reading the csv using  `readr::read_csv()` so that you can parse the data into the required type by setting the `col_type` argument  as required: options include: " D = date, T = date time, t = time,".

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("3/12/2020", 
            "3/13/2020"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
            3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("00:00:00Z", "00:00:01Z", "00:10:04Z", 
            "00:25:12Z", "01:00:02Z"), class = "factor"), Text = structure(c(5L, 
            3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Government launch new policy to different sector", 
            "Launches of rocket", "Premium policy get activate by company abc", 
            "Technology makes trend", "The images of demonstrations and gatherings", 
            "Weather forecasting by xyz"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(1L, 
            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "improvement"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            -6L))
```

Creating the dataset df1 as above then running this gives you required plot for hour

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Time=hms(Time),
         Date=mdy(Date),
    hour=hour(Time)) %>% 
  count(hour) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour,n,group=1))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

Comment: How we plot the tweets per hour because text column contains various tweets entries in text format at several interval of time includes hour min and second as I mentioned.

Comment: This should plot it on hourly basis

Comment: It's not plot correctly. We have large dataset of tweets nearly 65000 rows of 15 days. how we should plot that shows the number of tweets done on hourly basis. I think due to huge dataset if I plot every minute and second it conflicts and not visualize properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem with the date-time format. Could you help how to wrangle it in proper date time format given dataset

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
```

#### Answer with your data

To demonstrate data wrangling.

```
# your data; 
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                       .Label = c("2020-03-12","2020-03-13"), 
                                       class = "factor"), 
                      Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L,3L, 4L, 5L), 
                                       .Label = c("00:00:00Z", "00:00:01Z", "00:10:04Z","00:25:12Z", "01:00:02Z"),
                                       class = "factor"),
                      Text = structure(c(5L,3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L),
                                       .Label = c("The images of demonstrations and gathering", "Premium policy get activate by company abc",
                                                  "Launches of rocket", "Premium policy get activate by company abc",
                                                  "Technology makes trend", "The images of demonstrations and gatherings", "Weather forecasting by xyz"), class = "factor")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))

# data wrangle
df2 <- 
  df1 %>% 
  # change all variables from factors to character
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(Time = str_remove(Time, "Z$"), #remove the trailing 'Z' from Time values 
         dt = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time, sep = " ")), # change text into datetime format using lubridtate::ymd_hms
         dt = ceiling_date(dt, unit="hour")) %>% # round to the end of the named hour, separated for clarity
  group_by(dt) %>%  
  summarise(nr_tweets = n())

# plot

p1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(dt, nr_tweets))+
        geom_line()+
        scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d/%m")+
        ggtitle("Data from question `df1`")
```

#### Answer with made up large dataset

```
tib <- tibble(dt = sample(seq(ISOdate(2020,05,01), ISOdate(2020,05,15), by = "sec"), 10000, replace = TRUE),
             text = sample(c(letters[1:26], LETTERS[1:26]), 10000, replace = TRUE))


tib1 <- 
  tib %>% 
  mutate(dt = round_date(dt, unit="hour"))%>% 
  group_by(dt) %>%  
  summarise(nr_tweets = n())


p2 <- ggplot(tib1, aes(dt, nr_tweets))+
        geom_line()+
        scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d/%m")+
        ggtitle("Result using `tib` data made up to answer the question")
  

p1/p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This version includes code to wrangle your data into suitable format.